# Subscription mode deprecated

Tags: angular, deprecated

Using intellij for Angular the ide show me this advice:

```
deprecated 
Observable<LoginResult>.subscribe(     
next?: (value: LoginResult) => void,     
error?: (error: any) => void,     
complete?: () => void): 
Subscription

Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8. Details: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments
 
rxjs
```

On this subscribe.

[the advice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSxqw.png)

```
    this.loginService.login(request)
      .subscribe(
        next => (data: LoginResult) => {
        if (this.authService.setToken(data.tokenType, data.accessToken)) {
          localStorage.setItem('eMail', request.email)
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      }, error => {
        alert(error.error.message)
      });
```

Anyone know the correct way to use subscribe in this case?
Thx!

For now i don't think we update angular, but in future we don't want do rewrite every subscription :D

Comment: The deprecation message _tells you_ what to do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the subscribe argument an object with `next`/`error` key :

```
this.loginService.login(request)
  .subscribe({
    next: next => (data: LoginResult) => {
      if (this.authService.setToken(data.tokenType, data.accessToken)) {
        localStorage.setItem('eMail', request.email)
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }
    }, 
    error: error => {
      alert(error.error.message)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Okay, it works.
Effectively, as it was pointed out to me, the message was telling me what to do. Fatigue plays tricks on you. Thanks for the answer with example, applying it also in other points of the code solves the report.

Comment: Isn't `(data: LoginResult) => { ... }` enough instead of `next => (data: LoginResult) => { ... }`? : ]

Answer (score 0):

`subscribe` isn't deprecated, only the variant you are using is deprecated.

Try this:

```
this.loginService.login(request)
  .subscribe({
    next => (data: LoginResult) => {
    if (this.authService.setToken(data.tokenType, data.accessToken)) {
      localStorage.setItem('eMail', request.email)
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    }
  }, error => {
    alert(error.error.message)
  }});
```

`subscribe` will only take one argument and that is Observer.
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Answer (score 0):

Let change your code to use different overload of `subscribe(...)`:

```
this.loginService.login(request).subscribe({
    next: (data: LoginResult) => {
        if (this.authService.setToken(data.tokenType, data.accessToken)) {
            localStorage.setItem('eMail', request.email)
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
    },
    error: error => {
        alert(error.error.message)
    }
});
```